# Is RewriteRule in one .htaccess file allowed to pass to a RewriteRule in another one?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I was wondering: If I had a directory with `.htaccess` file inside it with a code similar to below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) subDirectory/$1 [NC,L]
```

And in the `subDirectory/`, I had another `.htaccess` file as so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) subSubDirectory/$1.html [NC,L]
```

Will it work? Provided that there is the file that we are targeting in the request. I've tried this and it didn't work for me and I suspect it is because apache doesn't allow you to pass URIs to their sub-directories.

A clarification would be most welcomed.

Comment: The error shown is:
`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `subDirectory/`, you can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ subSubDirectory/$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks... I think the condition was missing.